# Adding Cookies on a website that redirects (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I would like to access a website through Selenium webdriver however the captcha system redirects you to another domain immediately if you don't have cookies set. The problem is that you can only set cookies in Selenium if you stay on the domain instead of getting redirected.
How do you set the cookies for the domain so you won't get redirected?